# boost::test and verifying code is executed

Tags: c++, boost, boost-test

I have a test that is successful (among other things) if a certain callback is run exactly N times.  Of course, I can write a bit of code to count how many times the callback is run and then execute a boost::test case against that condition.  But this has arisen so often I wonder if I've missed some support for this in boost::test.

Many thanks for any tips.

Comment: Twelve days have passed.  I conclude that the best approach is to handle the case myself, as indeed I already do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish that with [mock objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object). [Turtle](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/turtle/index.php?title=Turtle) is a mock library that integrates quite well with Boost::Test.

Comment: This is an interesting and useful approach, thanks.  In my simple case, I'm not sure it adds much beyond what I get from handling the count myself, but in slightly more complex scenarios I suspect it would be quite helpful.  [Since it's a useful answer and the only answer after many weeks, I'm also accepting it.]

Answer (score 0):

Boost.Test has a subsystem for testing interactions. Admittedly, it is poorly documented, but BOOST_TEST_LOGGED_EXPECTATIONS will do exactly what you need. You do indeed need to mock the party you interfacing with. Boost.Test has a mock class for that.